# Find if any set is covered by member sets

Tags: algorithm, set

[Please let me know if this maps to a known problem]

I have n sets of varying sizes. Each element in a set is unique. And each element can occur atmost in two different sets.

I want to perform an operation on these sets but avoid duplicates or missing any element.
Problem: Find out which all of these n sets should be removed because they are covered by other sets.

E.g. [a,b,c]; [a]; [b]. Remove [a], [b] since both are covered by the first one.

E.g. [a,b,c]; [a]; [b]; [c,d]. Remove [a,b,c] since all three elements are covered by remaining sets. 
Note: here [a],[b] alone is not valid answer since 'c' is being duplicated. Similarly [a],[b],[c,d] is not valid answer since 'd' will be missed if removed.

Comment: What is the expected number of sets? Maximum number of elements in a set? Maximum number of different elements?

Comment: Note that in general there may be no solution. For example, with sets {a,b}, {b,c}, {a,c}, there is no cover of {a,b,c} that avoids elements being duplicated.

Comment: Well, in my scenario, I expect around 10s of sets; # of elements in a set could be 1000s though (same for max number of elements). But I asked this problem from an algorithmic perspective. The {a,b}{b,c}{c,a} has more than two copies of a,b,c.

Comment: For the collection `{a,b}{b,c}{c,a}` each of `a`, `b`, and `c` is in exactly two sets. How does this violate your conditions?

Comment: What would be the result of [a,b,c,d], [a,e], [b,c], [d,e]?

Comment: @Ted, You're right; my mistake. In fact, looking at these examples I realize that my problem is even more constrained than what I mentioned above (in a bid for simplification, I missed that constraint). Let me update after a bit more thinking.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is the [Exact Cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover_problem). The last constraint—that each element is in at most two sets—doesn't seem to me to fundamentally change the problem (although I could easily be wrong about this). The Wikipedia web page contains a good summary of various algorithmic approaches. The algorithm of choice seems to be [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links).

Comment: Since a number can appear only once or twice, this is easier than exact cover.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a case of a [2-sat problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability) that can be solved in linear time using a [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Strongly_connected_components) based on [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

1. Make a variable Ai for each set i.  Ai is true if and only if set i is to be included.
2. For each element that appears in a single set add a clause that Ai=1
3. For each element that appears in 2 sets i and j, add clauses (Ai && ~Aj) || (~Ai && Aj).  These clauses meant that exactly one of Ai and Aj must appear.

You can now solve this using a standard 2-sat algorithm to find whether this is impossible to achieve or a satisfying assignment if it is possible.

For a case with V sets and N elements you will have V variables and up to 2N clauses, so Tarjan's algorithm will have complexity O(V+2N).

Comment: I'm thinking this is correct, and essentially equivalent to my answer. I suspect this may have less overhead then mine, and thus run faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since an element in a set can appear in no more than two sets, then there are fairly straightforward connections between sets, which can be shown as a graph, the two examples are shown below. One example uses red lines to represent edges and the other uses black lines to represent edges.

[image: Graph Example]

The above shows that the sets can be divided into three groups.

1. Sets where all elements appear twice. These sets could potentially be removed and/or the sets that contain those elements could be removed.
2. Sets where one or more elements appear twice. The elements that appear twice could potentially link to sets that could be removed.
3. Sets where no elements appear twice. These sets can be ignored.

It's not really clear what happens if all of the sets are in either group 1 or group 3. However there seems to be a fairly simple criterion that allows for quickly removing sets, and the psudocode looks like so:

```
for each set in group2:
    for each element that appears twice in that set:
        if the other set that contains that element is in group1:
            remove the other set
```

The performance is then linear in the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks all for the various solutions!

Comment: It's probably not a bad idea to implement each of them and see which works best.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find which sets to include rather than remove. Something like this?

(1) List of elements and the indexes of sets they are in

(2) Prime the answer list with indexes of sets that have elements that appear only in them

(3) Comb the map from (1) and if an element's set-index is not in the answer list, add to the answer the index of the smallest set that element is in.

Haskell code:

```
import Data.List (nub, minimumBy, intersect)

sets = [["a","b","c","e"],["a","b","d"],["a","c","e"]]
lengths = map length sets

--List elements and the indexes of sets they are in

mapped = foldr map [] (nub . concat $ sets) where
  map a b = comb (a,[]) sets 0 : b
  comb result   []     _     = result
  comb (a,list) (x:xs) index | elem a x  = comb (a,index:list) xs (index + 1)
                             | otherwise = comb (a,list) xs (index + 1)

--List indexes of sets that have elements that appear only in them

haveUnique = map (head . snd)
           . filter (\(element,list) -> null . drop 1 $ list) 
           $ mapped

--Comb the map and if an element's set-index is not in the answer list,
--add to the answer the index of the smallest set that element is in.

answer = foldr comb haveUnique mapped where
  comb (a,list) b 
    | not . null . intersect list $ b = b
    | otherwise                       = 
        minimumBy (\setIndexA setIndexB -> 
                    compare (lengths!!setIndexA) (lengths!!setIndexB)) list : b
```

OUTPUT:

```
*Main> sets
[["a","b","c","e"],["a","b","d"],["a","c","e"]]

*Main> mapped
[("a",[2,1,0]),("b",[1,0]),("c",[2,0]),("e",[2,0]),("d",[1])]

*Main> haveUnique
[1]

*Main> answer
[2,1]
```